# Deploy EJB with Velocity in Glassfish generates java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, velocity, noclassdeffounderror

I need you help. I am working in a EJB that requires the velocity library, but when i deploy and run the EJB, a exception is thrown: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties

I don't understand why. When i use the class directly in the Session Bean, there are no problem. But when this class is instantiate from Velocity i receive the exception

I have tried declaring the library as directly dependency. Deploy the EJB in the Glassfish console configurating Libraries field with the same result

Server:  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)

SO: Windows 7

JDK: 1.7.0 21

Netbeans 7.3.1

I simplified the case with this code:

```
package test.mavenproject1;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;

@Singleton
public class NewSessionBean {

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*")
    public void businessMethod() {
        ExtendedProperties p = new ExtendedProperties();
        p.addProperty("test", "A");
        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        Logger.getLogger(NewSessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, p.getString("test"));
    }
}
```

And the POM File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject1</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The output:

```
WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4088)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1832)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$100(EJBTimerService.java:108)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:2646)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.<init>(RuntimeInstance.java:183)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.<init>(VelocityEngine.java:60)
    at test.mavenproject1.NewSessionBean.businessMethod(NewSessionBean.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4058)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppLibClassLoaderServiceImpl$URLClassFinder.findClass(AppLibClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem is a possible bug of Glassfish. My project is made with Maven, if i use a library that requires other library, the classes in the last library are not found.

The workaround is to put the jar libraries in the domain lib directory, restart the server and the problem is left.

For my example, I have downloaded commons-collections and commons-lang, and put these on {domain-directory}/lib

After this, my ejb runs ok.